# Programmatically filing IRS 1099 documents without using FIRE

Tags: tax, irs

Is there a way to submit IRS 1099 document(https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-1099-nec) programmatically? 1099 documents can be submitted through FIRE https://fire.irs.gov/, but it requires a manual process to upload the files. I'm wondering if there's a way to do it without using FIRE.

I know some companies provide API for submitting documents (e.g. https://docs.withabound.com/docs/1099-nec), and I would like to know how they are achieving that.

Comment: Are you sure you want to have a bot file taxes for you? A trivial runtime error code could lead to a lot of issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, it turned out FIRE is the only option for us to submit files as of 2022

Answer (score 0):

There is the new IRIS portal apart from FiRE

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: hi @user22300404 Would you care to share the link? I haven't been able to find their new system